# How to put svg image in Xamarin.Android application's screen?

Tags: image, svg, xamarin.android, screen

I want an image to ocuppy `40%` of the screen of `Xamarin.Android` application. But as the application will have to display well on devices between `5 and 10 inches` I put a `.svg` image to prevent the pixeling no matter how much the screen size increases. When I run the application the image doesn't appear on screen. My question is how can I put `.svg` image in `Xamarin.Android`'s application screen? Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--The svg image that has to ocuppy 40% of the screen goes here-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/svg_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--The rest of the things that have to ocuppy 60% of the screen go here-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact,Android does not provide an API method for parsing .SVG file directly.

And there are two solutions:

1.Use the third party library (like [Xamarin.FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading)).

2.Convert SVG to Vector (i think it's much better than using any libraries)

You could creating SVG vector drawable by using [this](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/),after you convert it to vecor drawable,you will get a `vector.xml`,put it into `Resources/drawable` folder.

Then you could use like

```
_yourImageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Vector);
```

Comment: Is this still same 2022 was native support not added recenlty?

Comment: how to achieve PCL in xamarin forms? dynamically xml file to view in svg image